# Prove that pseudorandom generator is a one way function

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, one-way-function

Suppose the following PRG $G : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow  \{0,1\}^{n +l}$, I want to prove that $G$ is one way function (and not building one), for:

1. $l = \omega (\log n)$
2. $l = 1$

For $l = \log n$, suppose that $G$ isn't OWF, so there's an inverter $A$ which succeeds w.p. $\geq 1/p(n)$, trying to build a distinguisher $B$ from inverter $A$ to $G$, I can do as follows:

$B(y)$ assigns 1 to each input successfully inverted. So $\Pr[B(y) = 1 : y = f(x) = G(x)] \geq 1/p(n)$, and for random input $\Pr[B(U_{n + \log n})] \geq 2^{n}/2^{\log n + n}$. All in all, the distinguisher succeeds w.p.

$$|\Pr[B(y) = 1 : y = f(x) = G(x)] - \Pr[B(U_{n + \log n})]| \geq 1/n - 1/p(n) \geq 1/2n$$

But for $l=1$, I get a bound of $1/4$ ($1/2 -1/p(n) \geq 1/4$)... It doesn't feel correct, but does (?) follow the definition of distinguisher for PRGs.

What am I missing?

Comment: From the question, it's completely unclear what you are actually doing, and then where the problem is. But maybe [this question and answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/is-pseudorandom-function-also-a-one-way-function) is helpful to you. However, the properties of PRFs, PRGs and OWFs are to some degree related but not the same. For a correct proof the details matter.

Comment: @tylo I updated the question, could you look again?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why 1/4 is sufficient advantage for a PRF distinguisher? Your proof itself - though missing a lot of details - would appear to be on the right track.

Comment: I want to prove that $G$ is OWF. 1/4 is enough, because its PRG should be computional indistinguishble for any negligible function, and 1/4 is greater for any negligeble function

Answer (score 2):

$$l = \log n: \Pr[B(Un+\log n)]≥2^n/2^{n+\log n} \cdot 1/p(n)$$
Since even if the input of $B$ is from the image of $G$, the probability to invert it is $1/p(n)$.
So you need to correct this case and it will help you with $l = 1$.

Comment: Firat of all, shouldn't your bound be $\leq$ (cause otherwise you can't bound $|\Pr[B(G(U_n)) = 1] - \Pr[B(U_{n + \log n})]|$)? Second, if I follow your way, for $l = \log n$ we get bound of $1/2p(n)\log n$, and for $l = 1$ we've get a bound of $\geq 2^n/2^{n+1}/p(n) = 1/2p(n)$. Am I correct? And finally, I stiil don't understand what's wrong with my previous way.

Comment: in the random case, it's not enough to be from the image. first of all, it should be from the image and then A should invert it right the second is done with probability 1/p(n).

Comment: Indeed, but now how you can bound from below, the substraction of two prob. which theoretically can both be big?

Comment: $1/p(n) - 2^{n}/(2^{n+1}*p(n)) = 1/p(n)$ so G isn't a PRG